# HSQL Statenment with sum in Java doesnt work

Tags: java, sum, hsqldb

im using a embedded hsql database in my java programm.
I want to write a hsql statement like this:

```
statement.executeQuery("SELECT sum(Points) FROM Table");
```

At first i tried this one:

```
String column = "Points";   

statement.executeQuery("SELECT sum(\""+column+"\") FROM \""+table+"\"");
java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: Points
```

Next one:

```
statement.executeQuery("SELECT sum(POINTS) FROM \""+table+"\"");
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: POINTS
```

Next try, should never been working but only for you :-)

```
statement.executeQuery("SELECT sum(\'"+column+"\') FROM \""+table+"\"");
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in operation
```

if i try this one:

```
statement.executeQuery("SELECT \""+column+"\" FROM \""+table+"\"");
```

runs perfectly

Just to show you that my column exist in my table.

This statement:

```
SELECT sum("Points") as test FROM "MyTable"
```

runs in SQuirrel Client Version 3.7

Any idea with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The same statement that works in SQuirrel should work. This is the same statement with Java quoting:

```
statement.executeQuery("SELECT sum(\"Points\") FROM \"MyTable\"");
```

It looks like you are connecting to a different database from your program and from SQuirrel. Try using the same absolute path to the database file in SQuirrel and in your program. You cannot connect at the same time, so you need to shutdown the database in SQuirrel before you connect from your program.

Comment: That is not the problem. Squirrel is shutdown while iam connect to DB with my java-program.

Comment: The problem is you are not connecting to the same database files.

Comment: The Problem is not this one! Squirrel conncet to the same db. I think the sum statement need other quotes.

Comment: I have added the Java equivalent to the statement that you say works in SQuirrel

Comment: Thank you for your works but your statement is the same like this                 
statement.executeQuery("SELECT sum(\""+column+"\") FROM \""+table+"\"");
java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: Points          I try your statement got the same Exception

Answer (score 0):

These are my imports

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
```

This Statment also not run:

```
statement.executeQuery("SELECT sum(\"Points\") FROM \"MyTable\"");
```

SOLUTION for maybe others:

```
"SELECT sum(\"Punkte\") as TEST FROM \"Match_Stats\"");   
while(table_01.next()){
    players.get(i).setPoints(table_01.getInt("TEST"));
}
```

Alias TEST was the key.

Comment: OK, I GOT IT! I need to write an alias for column Points. "SELECT sum(\"Points\") as TEST FROM \"MyTable\""); The problem was not the Statement but table_01.getInt("Points"). Changed it to table_01.getInt("TEST") and it works. Someone know why?

Comment: It's because `sum("Points")` is not a column named `"Points"`.